# Problems using Spark 1.6.2 for Hadoop 2.6.0 in a Hadoop 2.7.1 cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have access to a Hadoop cluster, version 2.7.1, that was installed using HDP 2.4. Such a cluster has Spark installed, specifically:

```
$ cat /usr/hdp/2.4.3.0-227/spark/RELEASE 
Spark 1.6.2.2.4.3.0-227 built for Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227
```

I'm trying to set up a "client" machine able to remotelly connect to the cluster and deploy Spark jobs. Thus, I need to install a Spark distribution for the same versions above.

First of all, I've gone to the official Spark download page, but 1.6.2 is only available for Hadoop 2.6.

Then, I decided to download Spark source code and build it by following [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/building-spark.html) guide. The interesting thing is the [required building profile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/building-spark.html#specifying-the-hadoop-version) for Hadoop "2.6.x and later 2.x" is `hadoop-2-6`. I.e. if I build by myself Spark, I'll obtain a distribution as the one available in the official Spark download page.

Thus, I've gone with such official pre-built distribution of Spark 1.6.2 for Hadoop 2.6.0.

And it seems not to be working properly. I've submitted a Python script -a very simple one only creating a Spark context- and there is some kind of problem (only showing relevant parts of the log):

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster basic.py
...
17/08/28 13:08:29 INFO Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 8 NodeManagers
17/08/28 13:08:29 INFO Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (24576 MB per container)
17/08/28 13:08:29 INFO Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
17/08/28 13:08:29 INFO Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
17/08/28 13:08:29 INFO Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
17/08/28 13:08:29 INFO Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
17/08/28 13:08:36 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/Users/frb/Applications/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar -> hdfs://<host>:8020/user/frb/.sparkStaging/application_1495097788339_0066/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar
17/08/28 13:14:40 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:basic.py -> hdfs://<host>:8020/user/frb/.sparkStaging/application_1495097788339_0066/basic.py
17/08/28 13:14:40 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/Users/frb/Applications/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/pyspark.zip -> hdfs://<host>:8020/user/frb/.sparkStaging/application_1495097788339_0066/pyspark.zip
17/08/28 13:14:41 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/Users/frb/Applications/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip -> hdfs://<host>:8020/user/frb/.sparkStaging/application_1495097788339_0066/py4j-0.9-src.zip
17/08/28 13:14:42 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/private/var/folders/cc/p9gx2wnn3dz8g6yf_r4308fm0000gn/T/spark-0d86f1f4-d310-423a-9d2f-90e2ff46f84e/__spark_conf__3704082754178078870.zip -> hdfs://<host>:8020/user/frb/.sparkStaging/application_1495097788339_0066/__spark_conf__3704082754178078870.zip
17/08/28 13:14:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: frb
17/08/28 13:14:42 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: frb
17/08/28 13:14:42 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(frb); users with modify permissions: Set(frb)
17/08/28 13:14:42 INFO Client: Submitting application 66 to ResourceManager
17/08/28 13:14:42 INFO YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1495097788339_0066
17/08/28 13:14:48 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/08/28 13:14:48 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1503918882943
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: <host>:8088/proxy/application_1495097788339_0066/
     user: frb
17/08/28 13:14:49 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: ACCEPTED)
...
17/08/28 13:14:52 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: RUNNING)
17/08/28 13:14:52 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.95.120.6
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1503918882943
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: <host>:8088/proxy/application_1495097788339_0066/
     user: frb
17/08/28 13:14:53 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: RUNNING)
...
17/08/28 13:14:59 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/08/28 13:14:59 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: N/A
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: -1
     queue: default
     start time: 1503918882943
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: <host>:8088/proxy/application_1495097788339_0066/
     user: frb
17/08/28 13:15:00 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: ACCEPTED)
17/08/28 13:15:01 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: RUNNING)
17/08/28 13:15:01 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: N/A
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.95.58.21
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1503918882943
     final status: UNDEFINED
     tracking URL: <host>:8088/proxy/application_1495097788339_0066/
     user: frb
17/08/28 13:15:02 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: RUNNING)
...
17/08/28 13:15:09 INFO Client: Application report for application_1495097788339_0066 (state: FINISHED)
17/08/28 13:15:09 INFO Client: 
     client token: N/A
     diagnostics: Max number of executor failures (4) reached
     ApplicationMaster host: 10.95.58.21
     ApplicationMaster RPC port: 0
     queue: default
     start time: 1503918882943
     final status: FAILED
     tracking URL: <host>:8088/proxy/application_1495097788339_0066/
     user: frb
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Application application_1495097788339_0066 finished with failed status
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1034)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1081)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
17/08/28 13:15:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
17/08/28 13:15:09 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory /private/var/folders/cc/p9gx2wnn3dz8g6yf_r4308fm0000gn/T/spark-0d86f1f4-d310-423a-9d2f-90e2ff46f84e
```

If I check the logs for this job, I see that:

```
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 690, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic.py", line 36, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 115, in __init__
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 172, in _do_init
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 235, in _initialize_context
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1062, in __call__
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 631, in send_command
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 624, in send_command
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 579, in _get_connection
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 585, in _create_connection
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 697, in start
py4j.protocol.Py4JNetworkError: An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server
ERROR:py4j.java_gateway:An error occurred while trying to connect to the Java server
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/disk0/hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/frb/appcache/application_1495097788339_0066/container_e03_1495097788339_0066_02_000001/py4j-0.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 690, in start
    self.socket.connect((self.address, self.port))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I.e. the Spark context is not created, the connection fails between the JVM running the Java gateway and the Python driver running the Spark Context.

This must be related to the Spark distribution I've installed in my client machine for sure, because:

- The Spark distribution of my client machine is uploaded to the clsuter, thus it is the one used; just remember this log when submitting:

  17/08/28 13:08:36 INFO Client: Uploading resource file:/Users/frb/Applications/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar -> hdfs://:8020/user/frb/.sparkStaging/application_1495097788339_0066/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar
- The same above command works when submitted within the cluster, i.e. when using the "Spark 1.6.2.2.4.3.0-227 built for Hadoop 2.7.1.2.4.3.0-227" version of Spark installed by HDP.

Any idea about how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly solved this:

- I added to the `spark-submit` command the option `--conf spark.yarn.jars`, with value the location of the Spark assembly jar in the remote Spark cluster. This avoids uploading the client-side Spark assembly jar I installed (which is a slow process, and does not exactly match the remote version, indeed).
- I added to the client-side of `yarn-site.xml` the property `hdp.version`, with value the HDP version of the remote Hadoop-Spark cluster. This avoids a substitution error in certain paths, which in the end was revealed as the connection error I described in the question.